# unable to connect using asp.net 4.5.x application to informix database using data server client sdk and .net provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, informix

I installed the current client sdk per the guidelines (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/index.html) from the  ibm_data_server_client_win32_v11.1. I was not able to conenct and continued to recieve the no information error **08001** with the extended information code

**Protocol specific error code(s): "", "", "0". SQLSTATE=08001 I noted the**

This particular error seems to indicate a failure to connect. I wanted to ask if anyone had been successful connecting to informix using the drivers and tutorial in the link above above after installing the extensions for visual studio 2015. The only protocol available to me on the db server is the **olsotcp** protocol which may be the problem. It may be that I am simply lacking the faith needed to continue to tinker with this when it does not seem to be working. I was able to connect when I installed the informix specific odbc drivers for windows. In this case, I can use the .net provider for odbc but I was hoping to avoid that. Any insight on what to do to make this work, what I may be missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the IBM Data Server .NET Provider you need to setup an DRDA alias on the engine.

Data Server drivers (DB2 drivers) use the DRDA protocol to communicate with the engine, so you need to have a "drsoctcp" (or "drtlitcp" if your IDS server is in a Sun box) to be able to use them.

It's not that complicate, create a new entry in the sqlhosts file with a new servername and add that to the DBSERVERALIASES key in the onconfig.

This is what I have in my linux box:

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ onstat -c | grep DBSERVER
# DBSERVERNAME    - The name of the default database server
# DBSERVERALIASES - The list of up to 32 alternative dbservernames, 
DBSERVERNAME irk1210
DBSERVERALIASES irk1210ssl,dr_irk1210,dr_irk1210ssl,irk1210pwd,irk1210pam
#                       
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ grep dr_irk12 $INFORMIXSQLHOSTS
dr_irk1210 drsoctcp irk 3047 
dr_irk1210ssl drsocssl irk 3048
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$
```

Any DRDA client (data server) would need to connect to "irk:3047"

More here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0207.htm